# what's the roadmap for cloud sql

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-datastore

Right now cloud sql limits no. of active connections to 100.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-discuss/F-OS6ucsSWE

Will this limit go away or increase in the near future and also we have a scenario where we are logging our users interactions in our system and store them in the db, which may hit the max. limit of sql connections. Should we look into cloud datastore so the database can auto scale and there are not limits or is it possible to achieve this somehow through GC-SQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud SQL now supports up to 3200 concurrent connections

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/pricing